# Syntax Error I can't figure out on Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I was attempting to change the conf of my files in order to achieve port forwarding, however all of a sudden I get the following error when attempting to restart:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

I'm new to Apach2 so I'd appreciate if someone could provide input on what could be going wrong. I can't figure out what exactly the syntax error is.

This is how my files look:
[00-defualt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbnUA.jpg)

[le-ssl file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6tG.jpg)

EDIT:

These are the lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER NAME}=19thstreet.co
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER NAME}%{REQUEST URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was the underscore in Request_URL:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Also the correct lines would be 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} 19thstreet.co
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]